# How do I tell sed to stop trying to process commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

Maybe I'm an idiot (this is the likely scenario, and I'm new to sed/bash scripting), but why does this work:

`NewVersion="$(echo $NewVersionFile | sed 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/')"`

But this does not:

`NewVersion={echo $NewVersionFile | sed 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'}`

The result of the second command is `sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unexpected }'`

How do I tell sed to quit doing anything after `'`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is this syntax supposed to achieve?

Comment: I'm attempting to automate the update process for software I get from Github. This portion is meant to get the version number of the latest release from another variable that has the name of the newly downloaded version which looks like `software-versionnumber.tgz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{` is a bash builtin that can be used to group commands.

```bash
{
    printf 'a\tb\n'
    printf 'c\td\n'
} | cut -f1
```

It's also used in parameter expansion

```bash
x=abc
echo ${x^^}
```

But you can't use it instead of `$(`; in fact, after an assignment, it has no special meaning, so it's part of the assigned value. That's why `sed` sees the closing brace:

```
NewVersion={echo $NewVersionFile | sed 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*/\1/'}
   ^        ^        ^           ^   ^                 ^
   |        |        |           |   |                 |
Variable Variable  Command     Pipe  Second     Argument of sed
 name     value    to run            command    (single quotes removed by quote
                                                 removal, but closing brace kept)
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I understand. I'm used to Powershell on Windows machines and this has proven more different than I expected. Thanks! One additional thing, is there a need for the double quotes in `"$()"`? What purpose do those serve?

Comment: In an assignment, double quotes around `$(...)` aren't needed. Elsewhere, double quotes around `$(...)` prevent word splitting. Read `man bash` for all the details.

Comment: @sirphillystax See ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) (note that the same rules apply to command substitutions).